# How to add a script file in Jenkins job workspace remotely and run it as part of build step

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to add a file to Jenkins Job workspace and run it from build step.

The Jenkins is on a remote folder and I cannot directly access workspace as a folder structure.

Is there any way to achieve this from Jenkins dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. In order to achieve that you can place your file in Git repository and then in the Jenkins job you can pull it and then you can execute it as a part of Jenkins job